# method calling and sending is off

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The code I have pasted below is 3 methods. The first method (maxLetterRecurrence) finds which letter occurs most, secondly I want to send the letter that occurs the most to the second function (printMax) so that I can print the letter which occurs the most in that function. Lastly I want to call the print fuction in my main function also called (secondaryMethodCalls) for right now. For some reason I can not get it correct. my counters work fine my error is between the second method(printMax) and the third (secondaryMethodCalls). PLEASE HELP! Sorry if indentation comes off wrong!

```
  import java.util.*;

 public class LetCount
{
    public static final int NUMCHARS = 27;

   // Method addr provided
   public static int addr(char ch)  
   {

   //int index[addr('ch')];
   //return (count[addr(ch)]+1);
   return (int) ch - (int) 'A' + 1; 
   }


 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   int[] count = new int[NUMCHARS];

   secondaryMethodCalls(count);
 } // end of main
 public static void secondaryMethodCalls(int[] count)
 {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String sampleInput= " ";
   do{
       sampleInput = keyboard.nextLine();
       System.out.println(sampleInput);
       letterCounter(sampleInput,count);

   }while(keyboard.hasNext());   

   printMax(max);
   print(count);
  //char finalMaxLetter = maxLetterRecurrence(count);
   //char finalMinLetter = minLetterRecurrence(count);
 }
 public static void letterCounter(String sampleInput, int[]count)
 {
   int length=sampleInput.length();
   for(int i=0;i<=length-1;i++)
   {

        char ch = sampleInput.charAt(i);
        if(ch >='A' && ch <= 'Z')
       {
           count[addr(ch)]++;
       }
    }

  }//end of letter counter



   public static void print(int[]count)
  {
      for(char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
   {
      System.out.println("letter recurrence:"+ch+"times="+count[addr(ch)]);
    }
  }
     public static char maxLetterRecurrence(int[] count)
  {
        char max = 'Z';
  int testVal = count[addr('A')];
  for(char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
  {
if(testVal < count[addr(ch)])
    {
  max=ch;
      testVal = count[addr(ch)];
    }
  }
  return max;
  }//end of max letter counter
  public static char minLetterRecurrence(int[] count)
  {
    char min = 'A';
     int testVal = count[addr('A')];
     for(char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
     {
      if(testVal > count[addr(ch)])
    {
      min = ch;
      testVal=count[addr(ch)];
    }
  }
   return min;
  }//end of min letter counter
  public static void printMax(char max int[] count)
  {
    char finalMaxLetter = maxLetterReccurence(count);
    System.out.println("most frequent letter:"+finalMaxLetter);
  }
} // end of class
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't it work or you just get errors and can't compile? If the secon one, ofc there is a problem that
'max' is not defined in secondaryMethodCalls and count is not defined ither in printMax. As long as they aren't global variables.

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question. It would be best to use comments in order to clarify what was asked rather than posting clarifiction questions as answers

Comment: the error I get is "can not find symbol" It wont compile. Why does max need to be define in secondaryMethodCalls if I'm just calling the printMAx method? Same question with count It's inside a method which I'm calling, why would I have to define it?

Comment: Need 50 reputation to comment :/

Comment: Why max needs to be defined? Are you a total amateur or I am just too stupid to understand the problem? :P

printMax(max);
You don't have max defined in the secondaryMethodCalls method and probably neither in class. You are trying to use a variable that does not exist.

Comment: Because I'm passing it from another function to another function. It only holds the memory address not the value.

Comment: Well, would you mind posting the whole class code then?

Comment: Sure. Give me one second.

Comment: posted! Sorry if indentation comes off wack in here.

Comment: Dude, it looks like you do basic mistakes. After copying the code into my IDE i get the following errors:
    public static void printMax(char max int[] count) - lacks comma between max and int
    char finalMaxLetter = maxLetterReccurence(count); - misspelled the method
    printMax(max); - max is not defined + printMax method has two parameters

Comment: No worries I figured it out. For some reason It was being weird about my function calls. I'm not sure what it was not liking maybe I was running broken code but thanks for your help!